# proxyquire not stubbing method call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, proxyquire

I'm trying to use `proxyquire` to replace a method call within a module I'm testing, but it is calling the method as is despite the fact I have the stub set up.  What am I doing wrong?

**formsReducer.test.js:**

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as actions from '../actions/formsActions';
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

describe('Forms Reducer', () => {
    describe('types.UPDATE_PRODUCT', () => {
        it('should get new form blueprints when the product changes', () => {
            //arrange
            const initialState = {
                blueprints: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        categoryId: 1,
                        identifier: null,
                        name: "Investment Policy Statement",
                        sortGroup: 1,
                        wetSignRequired: false
                    }
                ]
            };
            const testBlueprints = [{ id: 999, categoryId: 1, name: "Form Blueprint Loaded From Product ID 1", sortGroup: 1, wetSignRequired: false }];
            //use proxyquire to stub call to formsHelper.getFormsByProductId 
            let formsReducer = proxyquire.noCallThru().load('./formsReducer', {
              formsHelper: {
                getFormsByProductId: id => { return testBlueprints }
              }
            }).default;
            const action = {
                type: types.UPDATE_PRODUCT,
                product: {
                    id: 1,
                    accountTypeId: 1,
                    officeRangeId: 1,
                    additionalInfo: "",
                    enabled: true
                },
            };
            //act
            const newState = formsReducer(initialState, action);
            //assert
            expect(newState.blueprints).to.be.an('array');
            expect(newState.blueprints).to.equal(testBlueprints);
        }); 
    });
});
```

**formsReducer.js:**

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';
import formsHelper from '../utils/FormsHelper';
export default function formsReducer(state = initialState.forms, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_PRODUCT: {
        let formBlueprints = formsHelper.getFormsByProductId(action.product.id);
        formBlueprints = formsHelper.addOrRemoveMnDisclosure(formBlueprints, action.stateOfResidence.id);
        return objectAssign({}, state, {blueprints: formBlueprints, instances: []});
    }
}
```

`formsHelper.getFormsByProductId` is not returning `testBlueprints` as it should if it were properly stubbed via `proxyquire`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a feeling it is because of the `.default` when you load it. Are you transpiling your test code with babel? Can you edit your question to include the header section with your requires/imports? Also, you can try `./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register` as your npm test script.

Comment: Hi Mario, I use the `.default` because if I don't, `.load('./formsReducer')` returns the following (which is not a function - I used `console.log` to get this): `{ default : [Function: formsReducer] }` - when I tried to use this as a function in the test I got an error.  I have edited my question to include requires and imports as you requested - see if that helps you diagnose the problem further.

Answer (score 0):

`formsReducer.js` is importing `../utils/FormsHelper`, but proxyquire is trying to replace `formsHelper`. Try changing the proxyquire to:

```
proxyquire.noCallThru().load('./formsReducer', {
  '../utils/FormsHelper': {
    getFormsByProductId: id => { return testBlueprints }
  }
})
```

Comment: This worked when I used `../utils/FormsHelper` rather than the lower case version.  However, it required me to create a stub for `formsHelper.addOrRemoveMnDisclosure` as well - if I didn't, I got the following error: `TypeError: _FormsHelper2.default.addOrRemoveMnDisclosure is not a function` - this appears to be a babel error of some sort?  In the `proxyquire` documentation, it states that I should only have to replace the keys that I want to and ones that I don't replace keep their original functionality.

Comment: You're right, I mistyped the filepath. I've fixed it now. I think the docs mean that you can proxyquire some files while leaving others unchanged. You could do `proxyquire.noCallThru().load('./formsReducer', { '../utils/FormsHelper': { getFormsByProductId: id => { return testBlueprints }, addOrRemoveMnDisclosure: require('../utils/FormsHelper').addOrRemoveMnDisclosure } });`.